# Can we call karate feature file from karate hooks

Tags: java, karate

I have implemented karate hooks, and inside the afterScenario I want to call a feature file which will update the status of test pass/fail.

Is this the correct approach, and can we call karate feature file inside hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I have used afterFeature before:

```
* configure afterFeature =
"""
function(){
  karate.log('after feature:', karate.feature.name);
  karate.call('utils/cleanup_group.feature', {docId: 667898});
}
"""
```

**BUT I highly recommend against doing this.**

In the above case, developer had test cases that depended on test data, and so they felt like they had to do it this way.   THIS IS A CODE SMELL :  in reality, the test data should be such that testing it is idempotent and also dirty data wont negatively affect the tests.    If you find yourself wanting to do this, then you are thinking of the test architecture incorrecly IMHO.    It would work as a "hack" though.

Answer (score 0):

You can if you really want to, but personally I would not do it. Consider this as un-supported.